# Firemonkey Blur Effects and Background

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Anyone knows how can i make Blur Effects (eg. TGaussianBlurEffect) to work with transpant form (transparency = true) background ?

what i get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7m3v.jpg

what i expect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXqlz.jpg

Thank you

Here is the form source. Form is transparent, The Panel1 is opaque (top aligned) and Panel2 (client aligned) is semi-transparent with GaussianBlurEffect.

```
object Form44: TForm44
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form44'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  Transparency = True
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Align = Top
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 65.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    OnMouseDown = Panel1MouseDown
    object Label1: TLabel
      Position.X = 272.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
      Text = 'Drag Panel'
      TabOrder = 1
    end
  end
  object Panel2: TPanel
    Align = Client
    Opacity = 0.500000000000000000
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 415.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 2
    object GaussianBlurEffect1: TGaussianBlurEffect
      BlurAmount = 5.000000000000000000
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do exactly, you image don't show exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should edit your question to better describe your exact problem: what do you have already done, what you intend to have, which code you have already written. I don't understand how your image is related to the question.

Comment: I've updated the first post! Thank you

Comment: Reading the docs (help) for `TBlurEffect` it says *...class for creating an effect that blurs the texture of visible objects.* That needs to be understood as objects **on the form**, not objects **behind the form**. In VCL I would take a copy of the desktop behind the form to an e.g. image on the form, but I have not done that in FMX, and thus unsure of how, especially in case you plan to do it on other OS's than Windows.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://github.com/grijjy/CodeRage2019/tree/master/BlurBehind

Comment: @TomBrunberg  unfortunately copying the form isn't the best solution even if can be done.

Comment: @DaveNottage I have tried and it does not work with transparency = true on the form.